# How to check whether a given value is already present in Arraylist<hashmap<key,value>>?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, contains

I have an `Arraylist<Hashmap<String,String>>` val2 which retrieves data from the `sqlite database`. I have used the same key name to insert contacts into database.Now i want to check whether a given value is already present in the `arraylist<hashmap<>>`. i want to use the `contains() function`. I am getting the result as false. Can anyone suggest me how to compare?
Here is my code:

```
                  Databsehandler.java
                public void insertcontact(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                 values.put("contacts", queryValues.get("c")); 
                 database.insert("userlogin", null, values);
               database.close();
             }   
                            public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllContacts() {
                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                 String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM userlogin";
                      SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
                        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                         do {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                 map.put("contacts", cursor.getString(3));
                      wordList.add(map);
         }                while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }


       return wordList;
      }
```

Contacts.java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>val2=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
val2=db.getAllContacts();
for(int i=0;i&lt;jArray.length();i++){


    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    s11=json_data.getString("phno");
    Log.e("phno from json",""+s11);
    Log.e("name from phone",""+name);
    if(s11.compareTo(phoneNumber)==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"value of s11"+s11,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for(int i1=0;i1&lt;val2.size();i1++)
        {
            if(val2.get(i1).containsValue(s11))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"true"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Datbasehandler.java

```
       query = "CREATE TABLE userlogin ( phoneId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,username TEXT,userid INTEGER,contacts INTEGER)";
```

Comment: I can't see `contains()` in this code.  Please also format it properly, it's very hard to read as it is.

Comment: k..I will improve on the formatting. Contains() is in contacts.java file.$th line from the bottom of the file

Comment: Do you mean `containsValue()`?

Comment: o sorry ..i meant containsValue()

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `userlogin`?

Comment: Phone numbers are usually `String`, and not `int`. For example, if you had a phone number 0800111222, once you write it to the DB it will be 800111222. So if you later have 0800111222 in your `jArray`, you will never find it in `val2`. Can this be the problem? If it is, changing your `CREATE TABLE` to `contacts TEXT` should resolve it.

Comment: i tried it doesnt work

Comment: Did you uninstall and re-install the app? Otherwise, the old definition of the table remains. Other than this, you'll need to post more information to get help - what data are you inserting to the DB (i.e. what are you passing to your calls to `insertcontact()`), and what data are you looking for but not finding (i.e. what's in `jArray`).